# Obfuscating the javascript but with passing in one data?

Tags: jquery, obfuscation

A little background: I am developing a website and a good deal of the work is done with my bookmarklet. People finding out how the bookmarklet works is very dangerous to my object and i need to hide it.
Problem is, the bookmarklet is generated on the spot.

It is pretty much a big mashup of jquery commands one after the other.

Is there any way for me to protect my code? I really dont want it to get leaked.. 
Ps: I know that its possible to de-obfuscate or just try to read it, but the audience is not as technically smart. They are good enough to read plain javascript however..

Note: I can just do JSON code where the actual data is transmitted as value to a variable, but i need to know an obfuscator that leaves variables semi-unchanged so as to ensure that my code gets through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use any obfuscator you can find on the web, but it still won't be protected, cuz anyone can deobfuscate it.

Consider refactoring of your code placing most valuable logic (eg. business logic) into backend and retrieve it with ajax. It's the only way to keep your logic away from visitors.

Actually, it's not that easy to say without code example and explanation how it works. I bet there's a proper way to make your program work.

Comment: I already tried ajax, since the bookmarklet is designed to work on a https website, it doesnt work.I just want to add some level of security to the code. I have just thought of one way but i am not sure its possible, editing question now.

Comment: I still don't get it, why you want to obfuscate your code) If everything is on server side, you just do all the frontend stuff with javascript (like styling, animating etc.).
That's the way it supposed to be.